# Where does this thumbnail mentioning the In-Betweener come from (Marvel comics)?

Tags: story-identification, marvel, comics

From [this blogpost](https://edwardfeser.blogspot.com/2023/11/the-thomists-middle-ground-in-natural.html):

> [image: Man only wearing green pants saying dialogue:]
>
> He is the separator of actualities.
> He is the barrier between dichotomies.
> He is the all-powerful In-Betweener.

I tried Bing reverse image search, but no useful information came up, except that it most likely came from Marvel. Does someone more educated in comics know the exact issue this came from?

Comment: [List of known In-Betweener appearances](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Category:In-Betweener_(Earth-616)/Appearances)

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Thank you for directing me to a useful resource. 46 items is not too large to search through by hand.

Comment: He is not a prince. He is not a king. He is not a work of art or anything.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The image in question is from ***[Doctor Strange Vol. 2 #26](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Doctor_Strange_Vol_2_26)***. The character speaking is the [Ancient One](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Yao_(Earth-616)). The story is titled "The Return of the Ancient One!".

> DR. STRANGE: Is he mortal?
>
> ANCIENT ONE: No. Nor is he a force like that Astral Eye or the Dread Dormammu. He is, in truth, a concept--as is Eternity! He is the separator of actualities. He is the barrier between dichotomies. He is the all-powerful In-Betweener.
>
> [image: Doctor Strange Vol. 2 #26, page 17.]
>
> <sub>*Doctor Strange Vol. 2 #26* (December, 1977)</sub>